# How do I delay a systemd service so that nvm & node are correctly initialised before running?

Tags: startup, services, systemd, nodejs

I have the following service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Launch Demo

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/bin/bash /opt/Demo/launch_script.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The `launch_script.sh` performs `npm start` on our node server, however the version of node used on startup differs from what we've set as default. I believe this is because the service is running too soon.

How can we delay the service so that node versioning, and all other dependencies are sure to be in place. Bonus points if you can tell us how to run the service as the logged in user.

Comment: Also... Is this the right place for this question? It might not be a Ubuntu-specific issue.

Comment: If you can explain convincingly how your question is related to Ubuntu, it's on topic. Otherwise [Unix.SE] would be a better place for it.